# What does "aexp" mean in "fexp → [fexp] aexp (function application)"?

Tags: haskell

[Haskell report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html) says

```
 fexp → [fexp] aexp (function application)
```

Is it correct that  `fexp` means function application?

What does `aexp` mean? Is it defined as an expression used as an argument in a function application?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a variety of directions an answer to this could go in. To save people the effort of writing an answer in a direction that isn't helpful to you, could you answer the related question "What does `fexp` mean?", to show us what direction you would like to see an answer go? Just a few sentences should be enough to show what information you're trying to gather about `aexp`.

Comment: Or, can you indicate if you've run across [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) before, and if you're familiar with the standard methods of representing operator/expression precedence in a BNF grammar (e.g., `term ::= term '*' factor | factor`, etc.)?

Comment: The `fexp` rule produces a left-associative juxtaposition of "argument" expressions that are necessary, but not *sufficient*, to produce a function application. (Not sufficient, because the rule produces an expression like `3`, which is not a function application.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fexp → [fexp] aexp` is a [production rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science)) named *`fexp`*. It means that

```
e1 e2 e3 ... en
```

is actually parsed as

```
( ... ((e1 e2) e3) ... ) en
```

where each `ei` is parsed according to the *`aexp`* production rule, and *`n`* satisfies *`n >= 1`*.